# How to change my windows 8 domain password without physical keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, tablet, touchscreen

I have a Windows 8 tablet without keyboard. I want to change my account password, but in the manual:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/change-your-password

Windows authors states that I need to "Press Ctrl-Alt-Delete". But it's a tablet - I don't have a keyboard, and ctrl-alt-delete doesn't work on a virtual keyboard. Is it possible to change my domain password on a Windows 8 tablet without a keyboard or do I need to find a USB keyboard and attach it to the tablet?

Comment: Is it an actual MS Surface Pro, or a Windows 8 tablet made by someone else? If there is one, try pressing the Windows and Power buttons at the smae time.

Comment: There are actual hardware buttons that perform the function of `CTRL+ALT+DEL` look in the manual for the device on how to do this.

Comment: I's Sony Duo 11 in tablet mode. And a number of desktops with windows 8, touch screens and no keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Win8 available, so I can't say this will work for sure, but in Win7 you can change your password from the command prompt.  Full details are [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427), but the relevant parts are

> To change a user's password at the command prompt, log on as an administrator and type:
>
> **`net user user_name * /domain`**
>
> When you are prompted to type a password for the user, type the new password, not the existing password. After you type the new password, the system prompts you to retype the password to confirm. The password is now changed.
>
> Alternatively, you can type the following command:
>
> **`net user user_name  new_password`**

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I think that's just if you are trying to change someone else's password.  Unless their domain/GPO has specifically disallowed changing their own password, you should always be able to change your own.  Of course, if that is true then the whole question is moot anyway.

Comment: Since I am an admin on our network at work, I couldn't try it here, but I remembered that on my home network my kids have a non-admin account.  Remoted in and nope, you do have to be an admin to do it (at least on the machine, I don't have a domain at home).

Comment: That's good. Deleted my two comments because then they add nothing of value. (And I still didn't downvote.)